# Excel VBA Loop to next group of text then go up to the first blank cell and enter text string

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to the world of coding. I have groups of rows of cells with text in them and 2 blank rows in between. They are groups of 2 and 3 and are in columns A and B.

For each group of text I need to go to the last blank cell above the text in column B and then enter a "text string_text from the top row of that group cell A".

I tried to use this:

```
Sub FindBlankAndFill()

    Dim cnter As Integer    
    firstRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cnter = 0

    For i = 2 To firstRow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Select Case cnter
                Case 0: Cells(i, 2).Value = "Test Value"
                Case Else: Cells(i, 2).Value = ""
            End Select
            cnter = cnter + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

This worked only for the first group of text, then left the other groups completely blank. The above code also does not have so it will pull the cell value needed for the text string.

If you have any ideas or solutions, I would greatly appreciate the help.
In the After picture, the yellow cells are the cells that the VBA should add.  The part after the underscore of "Test Value" should be pulled from the cell in the A column for that particular group.

[Sample of Data before the VBA is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y807e.png)

[Sample of Data After the VBA is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FskL.png)

Comment: Don't understand what you're doing but you probably want to have `cnter = cnter + 1` outside the `if` statement?

Comment: An small example of your data (i.e. a screenshot) before and after (as it is expected to look) would be helpful.

Comment: I have added some pictures of the before and after data along with a small explanation.  Please let me know if any other information will be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried moving the cnter = cnter +1 outside of the if statement, but it did not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm was close. Basically, you're using the `cnter` variable to track which blank line you encounter, so the value needs to reset when you find more data. Your `firstRow` statement is really finding the `lastRow`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindBlankAndFill()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cnter As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cnter = 0

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Select Case cnter
                Case 0:
                    '--- found the blank row above the data
                    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Test Value_" & ws.Cells(i + 1, 1)
                    cnter = 1
                Case 1:
                    '--- found the blank row below the data,
                    '    so do nothing
            End Select
        Else
            '--- we found some data, so set the flag
            '    for when we find the next blank row
            cnter = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: PeterT, Thanks this seems to work exactly as I was hoping!